# Why can not I use the library dropzone?

Tags: html, css, dropzone.js

I have this sample:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/rfv0afgf/)

We implemented dropzone library which is found [here](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) and tried to use ...
Unfortunately code written by me (which I found on the official site) does not work

**CODE HTML:**

```
<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

Can you please tell me how I can use this library and see an example in jsdfiddle?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the text use this:

```js
$(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $(".dz-message").text("Drop tabs here to upload");
  }, 1500);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/dropzone.js"></script>

<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You code is fine. But the JS file you connected, not working. I've tested your code. Its correct. Also, You did not connect dropzone.css. Without it you wont get correct interface. Look at the snippet with dropzonejs linked from cdnjs.com

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/dropzone.js"></script>

<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

Comment: Now go ... just not working on my site (I can not give you because it is the local link)
If you put HTML code in and give refresh ... it disappears, nothing is printed in the area

Comment: What do you mean by "Now go.."? Here look at working JSFiddel - https://jsfiddle.net/zahedkamal87/rfv0afgf/1/

Comment: now working...ok but you can change the text to "drop tabs here to upload?"

Comment: Look at their documentation. You'll get all answers you need to use it. Or you can also look at their Github page  -  https://github.com/enyo/dropzone